# conflict on php.ini and magento

Tags: php, magento

I am stuck on a very strange problem whenever I place a local php.ini file on my siteground server and increase the `max_execution_time` magento stops working with below error. Even with empty php.ini file it is creating problem:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
Entity: line 2: parser error : error parsing attribute name  in 
    /home/omitted/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 22821

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', 
    '/home/omitted/...', 22821, Array)
#1 /home/omitted/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(22821): 
    simplexml_load_string('loadCache()
#3 /home/omitted/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21115): 
    Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#4 /home/omitted/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21045): 
    Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 /home/omitted/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/omitted/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

Searched a lot but couldn't find out the reason. Is this server issue or something wrong with the website?

Server -

- Memcached enabled
- HHVM enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try to add any default php.ini(from fresh magento folder as per your version) file in your website's folder.
If it will work then make changes for max_execution_time.

Comment: yes just  tried nothing changed. same error. seems like magento is not liking the presence of php.ini.

Comment: okay ..try to trace the issue from log file and check below url, it may help you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45633/php-ini-and-htaccess-files-missing-1-9-magento

Comment: problem resolved it was compiler causing the issue. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution Magento Compiler was causing the error. Just disabled the compiler, added php.ini and re-compiled. It worked.

Comment: MeganX  answered the question - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115130/strange-conflict-in-php-ini-and-magento

Comment: Great it works now. Please mark your answer as solution to your question. Thanks!